# Solr returns 500 exception for /solr/sitecore_master_index/update

Tags: solr, sitecore-api

We have deployed Sitecore into Azure. In Solr server we noticed a 500 exception(/solr/sitecore_master_index/update).
[image]

Sitecore log shows the below exception:

```
Exception: SolrNet.Exceptions.SolrConnectionException
Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">710</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_master_index\data\index\_46nao.fdx</str><str name="trace">java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_master_index\data\index\_46nao.fdx
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.IOUtils.fsync(IOUtils.java:471)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.fsync(FSDirectory.java:327)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.sync(FSDirectory.java:285)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.sync(NRTCachingDirectory.java:169)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.sync(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:68)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.startCommit(IndexWriter.java:4724)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3085)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3244)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commit(IndexWriter.java:3207)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:644)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:93)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1894)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1871)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessorFactory$LogUpdateProcessor.processCommit(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:160)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:281)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:188)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
</str><int name="code">500</int></lst>
</response>

Source: SolrNet
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
   at SolrNet.Commands.CommitCommand.Execute(ISolrConnection connection)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrBasicServer`1.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.Commit()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate(IEnumerable`1 indexableInfo, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
   at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

If anyone experienced a similar issue please let me know.

Comment: What exception do you see exactly in the Solr log, please?

Answer (score 1):

Solr throws a `NoSuchFileException` error because it tries to access an index file `D:\home\site\wwwroot\server\solr\sitecore_master_index\data\index\_46nao.fdx` that does not exist on your environment. Did you qualify that path?

You can use the local path while developing & running your Sitecore application on your local machine, use the relative path in Azure.

Once validated the path, I suggest to delete all indices in Azure and rebuild all from scratch.